# RSpec & DataMapper: How to stub the finder method correctly

Tags: xml-serialization, rspec, datamapper, factory-bot, stub

The environment is Sinatra, Nokogiri, RSpec, FactoryGirl and DataMapper.

The problem is with DataMapper's serializer. I don't know how to stub appropriatetely with it.

The problematic code:

```
specify 'should return an xml array of all municipalities' do
    municipalities = []
    10.times { |n| municipalities << Factory.build(:municipality, :code => "Municipality no #{n}") }
    Municipality.stub!(:all).and_return(municipalities)
    get "/municipalities.xml"
 #  ^------- KABOOM!
 #  [.. rest of code clipped out ..]
 end
```

The code which `get` calls is practically equivalent with:

```
 Municipality.all.to_xml
```

The problem is that the result set's type is `DataMapper::Collection` which has the `#to_xml` method.

My stub does not obviously work because I use an `Array` of stubbed instances, instead of a `DataMapper::Collection`.

My question is:

How should I create a collection of instances (with FactoryGirl) which are of type `DataMapper::Collection` and have the `#to_xml` method provided by DataMapper's serializer?

The code is also available at Github:

- [Spec](https://github.com/pre/apila/blob/69d6e02c3fc8019dc8cc35c5b568188140a92277/spec/application_spec.rb#L67)
- [Controller](https://github.com/pre/apila/blob/69d6e02c3fc8019dc8cc35c5b568188140a92277/application.rb#L55)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, you don't.

Because we know that:

- `.all` will always return a `DataMapper::Collection`

  - It should be tested in different **unit** test
- `.to_xml` will always return a XML representation of collection

  - It should be tested in diffenent **unit** test that has nothing to do with HTTP get etc.

So we can stop testing everything in one single test and split it up.

What you really want to test here is if the controller calls for Municipality.all AND then .to_xml for the collection it returns WHEN it get's called with a GET of `"/municipalities.xml"`

```
specify 'should return an xml array of all municipalities' do
  collection = mock(DataMapper::Collection (or anything, its not really interesting here))
  collection.should_receive(:to_xml).and_return(xml_if_needed_for_view)

  Municipality.should_receive(:all).and_return(collection)

  get "/municipalities.xml"
end
```

The code above is maybe somewhat pseudo.

Comment: Ok! Thanks for broadening my vision! :)